# Getting white screen in Login /user and the page content

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, users

I was recently editing a website with Drupal 7 installed, and was integrating twitter feed.

1. I created a block twitter_feed_block and assigned the block to the content section of the front page. It worked fine.
2. Then I tried to move to twitter_feed_block to multiple places (like right sidebar, header, menu etc). This move caused multiple contents on the main page to disappear.

Now every link in the website is showing a **white screen**. Sadly i tried to log out and login again and found the login at WEBSITE/user has also disappeared.

Attached a screenshot [image: About Us page]

Comment: What do you mean by **no content**? White screen? What do you mean by login disappeared?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting a white screen. Thanks. I have edited the question.

Comment: This is not a **white screen**.

Comment: Try to login again via `drush uli` and first of all remove the Facebook block you added earlier and try to add everything back.